# Weform textbox placeholder

Tags: 7, webforms

I know I can set "default value" for textbox in D7 webform. Unfortunately, user needs to remove the default value and key in their own information. Actually I want something like placeholder feature. How to do this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [Webform Hints](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_hints) module.

> This module allows users to enable automatic placeholders to
>   textfields, textareas, select lists, and email fields within a webform
>   created by the Webform module.

Answer (score 0):

That is built in webform 7x-4.7 D7 already (I'm assuming you mean 'textarea' when you say textbox).

Steps:
- Specific Wedform 'edit'
- Components tab and 'edit' on the particular component 
- Scroll down to "Display" header
- After height and width you should have "Placeholder", which is what it says.

Just add you text there. Behaves as placeholder text should.

Comment: Sorry is not textarea. It is text field. Normally I call textbox. Lol

Comment: Same instruction apply for text fields. No need to install another module for existing feature.

Comment: Solve!!!!! Form builder dun support this module. Once remove it works. Thanks piet!!!